# problem with admin panel

Tags: posts, admin, save-post

Absolutely new wordpress installation.
I'm adding a new record, it is not added. Writes what is published, but when I go to the "all records" section - there she appeared, but the previous one disappeared.

I recorded the video:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/14drbzc0hwbg5m1/admin.mov

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: are you able to see the page ? i mean on the front end

Comment: Previously published pages disappear after the publication of a new

Comment: @MaratPetrov you have a tonne of plugins and a custom theme, please disable everything, then turn it on 1 by 1 until the issue comes back to figure out where the problem is ( that includes your theme )

Comment: @TomJNowell deactivated plugins and changed theme
Problem still exists

Comment: it persists with the default theme and all plugins disabled? Have you made modifications to WP core? Are you sure you tested with **Everything** disabled? Theme, plugins, mu plugins, drop ins etc? All caching turned off?

Comment: @TomJNowell All plugins are disabled, no changes were made to the kernel.
Caching is disabled.
Maybe it is on the nginx line.
I will be grateful if you look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sivg62jixfstqau/it.txt?dl=0

Comment: The problem was in the ACF plug-in
Installed a new version
Thanks